# Deploy asp.net mvc 3 application with azure table storage as web site

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, azure

I'm new to azure, but I looked try the samples on offical azure site. I have developed
a 3 tier web application like so:

- dal layer with repositories (data in azure table storage and blob storage)
- service layer (contains logic and is using repositories in dal layer)
- ui layer (actual asp.net mvc 3 web site)

Visual Studio Solution contains 5 projects:
- Dal (class library)
- Service (class library)
- Objects (class library)
- UI (asp.net mvc 3 web site)
- Azure (azure cloud project, contains mvc UI project)

The site is running localy just fine. When I deploy application as a cloud service,
the thing works. But I noticed, that I don't have ftp support, so that my UI designer
could change css and html files. I deployed application as a web site (Publish on UI project), deploy succeeded, but application was not accessible. It throws an error, that
Dal dll is not accessible (yes, I marked copy local to true, and I looked on ftp there was Dal.dll also).

My question is: how can I deploy my application as web site? I'm sure that I'm doing something wrong.

Thank you for your help,
Jani

Answer (score 0):

In your ASP.NET MVC 3 web application, could you try referencing the following assemblies and set Copy Local to true for all of them:

- Dal
- Service
- Objects

Comment: I did referenced assemblies and set copy local to true. When I deployed web UI project I looked on ftp and all of the assemblies where there. I can't figure out what's wrong.